# Why form field stays filled after upgrading to AngularJS 1.3

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I used an AngularJS 1.2 application with a classic log-in/log-out function, ant it worked well.

When I log out, I make some basic operations then a redirection to log-in page (`$state.go('app.login');`)

However, the login page is loaded with the username and password already filled, which is pretty annoying :) It didn't occur with AngularJS 1.2.

Here is the login form:

```
<form name="LoginForm"
      autocomplete="off"
      ng-submit="validate_login(email, password)">
    <div class="list">
      <label class="item item-input my-item">
        <input name="email"
               ng-model="email"
               type="email"
               required
               placeholder="E-mail">
      </label>
      <label class="item item-input my-item">
        <input name="password"
               ng-model="password"
               type="password"
               required
               placeholder="Mot de passe">
      </label>
    </div>

    <button class="button" type="submit">
        Connexion
    </button>
</form>
```

Here is the content of the log out controller:

```
$scope.logout_user = function() {
    Auth.clearCredentials();
    $state.go('app.login');
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure they are not filled in by the browser? ALso, you should share some code if you want help on that

Comment: The form has an `autocomplete=false` so I don't think so. I added some code even if I’m not sure it would help. I actually expected the problem came from a new behaviour with routing in Angular 1.3, since everything was fine with Angular 1.2

Comment: It looks like the model is not reset. Try with an `ng-init="email=''; password=''"` or something like that. I don't know which router you are using but `ui-router` has an option to reload the controller while changing the state, and that could help.

Comment: The `ng-init="email=''; password=''"` statement has no effect in my case. Yes i'm using ui-router. Could you elaborate about this reload option?? Thanks!

Comment: I tried to add `$state.reload();` in my controller. The fields are still filled... I really don't understand what's going on!

Comment: then I would try to use a var declared in the controller, that gets reset every time the ctrl is reloaded `$scope.user = {email: '', password: ''}` and then is used in the form as `user.email` and `user.password`

Comment: It would work but I would prefer understand what's going on instead of a writing workaround. This behaviour is not normal. When rolling back to AngularJS 1.2.5, it works again. Thanks :(

Comment: I disagree that this is a workaround. In fact, I think that having a proper variable for that case would definitely be my preferred solution